# Short story where a creature wrapped in newspaper attacks a man

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify a science fiction short story I read many years ago, probably in the late 60s or early 70s. In it, a man living a typical suburban type of life goes outside to get his morning newspaper and comes back inside to discover that some kind of creature or machine has been wrapped in the newspaper. The smallish creature is described as white and rat like, and aggressive, as it immediately attacks the man. He fights it in his bathroom/bathtub, and although it's very durable he's successful in killing it. He goes outside afterward to see all of his neighbors being attacked by the same type of creature. This was probably in a short story collection book and not a magazine.

Comment: Hi there. That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, how long ago is "many years ago"? Ten years? The 80s? The 50s? :)

Comment: Thank you. I believe the time period was late 60s or early 70s, and it was probably in a short story collection book and not a magazine. I also remember that the creatures were small; again, rat-like in size. Also the protagonist fought the creature in the bathroom/bathtub in his house.

Comment: Nice, always useful info. Don't hesitate to [edit] it in, as well as any other memory teh linked guide might make you remember :)